# How to Run a C# console app with the console hidden style?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, console, hidden

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C#: Run external console program as hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430541/c-run-external-console-program-as-hidden)

I am using a Windows Forms application that needs to start a console app. I don't want the console app be displayed on windows task

I setting `p.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;`

But it doesn't work, the process is showing

Code:

```
ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo();

p.UseShellExecute = false;
p.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.FileName = "rasdial";
p.Arguments = string.Format("\x22{0}\x22", name);
p.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

Process process = Process.Start(p);
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by saying "I don't want the console app be displayed on windows task" ? The console window is not visible to the user?

Comment: I upvoted. I don't know what's going on StackOverflow, but the place is feeling increasingly hostile to questions (the reason everyone is here, in the first place).

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience. try any help here is it an error?

Comment: +1 to get 0. I think it is a good question, but it is a duplicate, so I have to flag it too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution:

```
p.CreateNoWindow = true;
```